# Passing a parameter to a function

Tags: powershell, user-defined-functions, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to create a simple function based on the following by passing an argument to it. The function will search my command history looking for a string - the command works:

```
history | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -match 'abc'}
```

From my research the closest thing to this would be:

```
Function FindHistory {history | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -match '$args'}}
```

However I am unable to get this (or any variation) to work.
`FindHistory abc` - should return all previous commands used with 'abc' in them.

What am I doing wrong?

btw, I've been an avid powershell user for all of 2 days - liking it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell won't expand variables in single quoted strings, so you have to use a double quoted string:

```
Function FindHistory {history | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -match "$args"}}
```

Though `$args` is an array of all arguments, so it may be more robust if you just specify a parameter:

```
Function FindHistory {PARAM($searchTerm)  history | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -match "$searchTerm"}}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully - thanks :) On a side note, your first comment with double quotes around args didn't actually work - didn't display desired result. The second worked a charm and hence marked as correct although being so new to Powershell I have no idea what exactly is happening with PARAM($searchterm) - it seems very similar to mjolinor's answer below but the below looks neater...

Answer (score 1):

Using $args in a where-object clause is problematic.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7821.powershell-using-args-in-script-blocks.aspx

Try this:

```
function findhistory ($search) {history | where-object {$_.CommandLine -match $search}}
```

Comment: works just as well as above and for a noob - easier to understand :)